# "Rate this app" stopped working on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, rate, review

The "`rate this app`" link stopped working from all my iOS published apps. Now when I hit the "rate it" button I get the following error message from the app store: `"Error Cannot connect to iTunes Store".`

My app was getting 20 reviews a day until the day before yesterday and yesterday I got none - so this is probably a worldwide issue.
The same also happened to a developer friend of mine. Of note, we both live in São Paulo (SP), Brazil.
Are you guys facing the same issue? Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: iOS6 has some issues: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4412155?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: First check whether your link is right (logging) and then try it several times. For me it worked after two times, or try the workaround from Craig.

Comment: This also may have to do with itunes down for maintenance. I got a email saying "iTunes Connect will be undergoing scheduled maintenance on Thursday, October 25 from 12 p.m. to 7 p.m. (Pacific)."   ... not sure if this is the problem, but I noticed that my published apps are having the same issue.

Comment: UPDATE: I think it was the iTunes connect maintenance issue.  My apps are know all working.. (Except on of them.. hopefully that will start working soon also)

Comment: The rate link is now working for some of my apps. Hopefully everything will be normalized soon.